# Are logs before Log End Offset(LEO) persisted in the disk?

Tags: apache-kafka

> High watermark is calculated as the minimum LEO(Log End Offset) across
>   all the ISR of this partition, and it grows monotonically.

My simple and stupid question is: Are logs before Log End Offset(LEO) persisted in the disk?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, the HW should have no direct relationship with flushed offset. Flushed offset should be the point where no data before it has not been persisted on disks due to Linux's default write-back strategy.

Say a partition commit log has 10 messages in it. HW is now 10 since all these 10 messages are fully replicated. Later the producer deliveries another 5 messages. Now the LEO(log end offset) is at 15, but HW is still 10 since these new-created 5 messages are not fully replicated by all followers. But remember this commit log is still in the pagecache, so due to the default writeback, it's very likely the kernel has not flushed all the messages to disk, so flushed offset might be before or after the HW.